# How to get elements after a sort on a dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, sorting

I have two matrices A & B and want to sort data on both using the 3rd dimension of A. For that, I use sort to get both result and indexes.

What I don't know is how to use the indexes to get sorted data on matrix B.

`A = rand(2,2,2)
B = rand(2,2,2)
[S I] = sort(A, 3);
S
B(I) % Here, don't sort B according to the same sort than A`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your third dimensional subscripts to linear indices with:

```
[r, c, ~] = size(A);
LinInd = (I-1)*r*c + reshape(1:r*c, r, c);  %For >=R2016b
%LinInd = bsxfun(@plus, (I-1)*r*c, reshape(1:r*c, r, c));   %For <R2016b
```

Now use these linear indices to sort `B` i.e:

```
B(LinInd)
```

Comment: I've been going in that direction, trying to use the function [sub2ind](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), thanks for the alternative. Matlab can be tricky sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Sardar Usama, the key is to transform the 3rd dimensional indexes into linear indexes. The correct function to do that in Matlab is [sub2ind](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html). It is not straightforward:

```
clc; clear all; close all;

n = 8;
A = rand(n, n, n);
[S, I] = sort(A, 3, 'descend');

sizeA = size(A);
sizeA1 = sizeA(1);
sizeA2 = sizeA(2);
sizeA3 = sizeA(3);

baseVecIndex1 = (1:sizeA1)';
bM1_2D = repmat(baseVecIndex1, 1, sizeA2);
bM1_3D = repmat(bM1_2D, 1, 1, sizeA3);

baseVecIndex2 = 1:sizeA2;
bM2_2D = repmat(baseVecIndex2, sizeA1, 1);
bM2_3D = repmat(bM2_2D, 1, 1, sizeA3);

linearIndexes = sub2ind(sizeA, bM1_3D, bM2_3D, I);

test = A(linearIndexes );
test(:, :, n)
S(:, :, n)
```